# How to end / close a MutableSharedFlow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

`SharedFlow` has just been introduced in coroutines 1.4.0-M1, and it is meant to replace all `BroadcastChannel` implementations (as stated in the [design issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2034) decription).

I have a use case where I use a `BroadcastChannel` to represent incoming web socket frames, so that multiple listeners can "subscribe" to the frames.
The problem I have when I move to a `SharedFlow` is that I can't "end" the flow when I receive a close frame, or an upstream error (which I would like to do to inform all subscribers that the flow is over).

How can I make all subscriptions terminate when I want to effectively "close" the `SharedFlow`?
Is there a way to tell the difference between normal closure and closure with exception? (like channels)

If `MutableSharedFlow` doesn't allow to convey the end of the flow to subscribers, what is the alternative if `BroadcastChannel` gets deprecated/removed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`SharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/index.html) documentation describes what you need:

> Note that most terminal operators like Flow.toList would also not complete, when applied to a shared flow, but flow-truncating operators like Flow.take and Flow.takeWhile can be used on a shared flow to turn it into a completing one.

> SharedFlow cannot be closed like BroadcastChannel and can never represent a failure. All errors and completion signals should be explicitly materialized if needed.

Basically you will need to introduce a special object that you can emit from the shared flow to indicate that the flow has ended, using `takeWhile` at the consumer end can make them emit until that special object is received.

Comment: This is indeed what the doc suggests, but I don't think this is enough to replace `BroadcastChannel`. We need a low-level primitive that would allow performant code behaving like broadcast channel. Materializing the close event through wrapper objects really makes me reluctant to make the move.

Comment: In theory you could use an `inline` class and a symbol object to create a wrapper with minimal overhead. It would essentially end up being an implementation of the "poison pill" pattern. Overhead limited to a referential equals check for each item.

Comment: I see, the symbol object could help. But as far as I remember inline classes do create wrapper objects when used as generics, which is the case in a `Flow<T>`, so I'm a bit weary about the efficiency of the wrapper (in terms of gc pressure for instance in case of high number of messages)

Comment: You're right, it seems generics force a boxed type. In that case you'll probably end up like many of the internal kotlin classes and use `Any` to represent a union of `ValueType | TerminationSymbol`, where it can be either the next value or the terminal symbol object. With a wrapper around the entire system you'd be able to maintain some type safety.

Comment: I didn't think of that, but I guess that could work. If it leaks into the API it's a no go of course, but for internal stuff it's actually an ok approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution is creating a boolean flag `isValid` and publicly expose only flows with `.takeWhile { isValid }`. Then just call `isValid = false` and `sFlow.emit()` when you want to close all subscribers.

Possible implementation:

```kotlin
private var isValid = true // In real scenario use atomic boolean
private val _sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>()
val sharedFlow: Flow<Unit> get() = _sharedFlow.takeWhile { isValid }

suspend fun cancelSharedFlow() {
    isValid = false
    _sharedFlow.emit(Unit)
}
```

*EDIT: In my case `.emit()` was always suspending so I had to use `BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST` (which is not suitable for many usecases). Not sure if the problem is in this example or elsewhere in my app. If you see a problem, please comment :)*

Comment: Yes, of course we can always use out-of-band information, but this is in general cumbersome, and I was looking for a more "native" way of doing this using the flow's API itself. It's true though that we can limit the scope of this out-of-band information to a minimum by ensuring we use `takeWhile` on every publicly visible flows. Good point.

Comment: Actually there are problems with this approach despite the synchronization hassle (at that would be enough to rule it out). Here `isValid` can become false before all consumers have consumed the last messages. This is a no-go, that's why the termination symbol usually needs to be part of the flow itself, so that consumers can reach it at their own pace.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't think of that... But I'll leave the answer here because it could be helpful for some usecases. Thanks for the reply @Joffrey

Comment: yea, really uncomfortable place in coroutine-flow. Why somebody resolved that share-flow could not be cancelled? It's just stupid, because every body want to have this possibility. Kotlin team have to resolve this problem. I don't want to make special objects in my code to cancel channels subscription in the end, I just want cancel it by one line!

Comment: And yes, @woodenleg - your solution is not enough reliable. Anyway finger up by attempt and idea

Answer (score 0):

just "played around" with a similar "challenge".

I wanted to "split" the result Flow of (possibly many) producers in a round-robin manner to multiple asynchronous consumers.

Achieving that:

- the producer produces a flow "in the background"
- one / many consumers consume chunks of the producers outcome in a round-robin fashion
  (also "in the background")
- while all of this happens, you can continue to "do something" until all data is produced AND consumed

To achieve the above I used `MutableSharedFlow` and after the producer (and consumers) finished "their" flows finally had to be canceled/finished.

I doubt that my result is in any way optimal or even a "good" solution, but as I have spend a "significant" time on it (learning) I thought I might share it here as well:

```kotlin
package scratch

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import okio.*
import kotlin.random.Random

data class Packet(val nr: Int, val cmd: String, val line: String, val isFinal: Boolean = false)
class TerminatedException(message: String, cause: Throwable? = null) : Exception(message, cause)

/** possible multiple producers sending to one MutableSharedFlow</br>
 *  multiple consumers fed round-robin from the one SharedFlow of all producers */
fun main(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") args: Array<String>) {
    println("===============================")
    println("====   multipleConsumers() ====")
    println("===============================")
    showcaseMultipleConsumers()

    println("\nmompl...\n")
    Thread.sleep(2000L)

    println("===============================")
    println("=====   singleConsumer() ======")
    println("===============================")
    showcaseSingleConsumer()

    println("main ended.")
}

private fun showcaseMultipleConsumers() {
    runBlocking {

        // launch producer with SharedFlow to emit to
        val producerFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Packet>()
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            producer(name = "producer", cmd = "/Users/hoffi/gitRepos/scratch/scratch/some.sh", producerFlow)
        }

        // launch concurrent consumers with each its own SharedFlow
        val consumerCount = 3
        val mapOfFlows = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableSharedFlow<Packet>>()
        for (i in 1..consumerCount) {
            mapOfFlows[i - 1] = MutableSharedFlow()
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                consume(i.toString(), mapOfFlows[i - 1]!!)
            }
        }
        println("finished launching $consumerCount consumers.")

        // round-robin emit from the producerFlow to the existing MutableSharedFlows
        var i = 0
        try {
            producerFlow.buffer().collect() { packet ->
                if (packet.isFinal) {
                    println("producer: final packet received"); throw TerminatedException("'producer' terminated")
                }
                mapOfFlows[i++ % consumerCount]!!.emit(packet)
            }
        } catch (e: TerminatedException) {
            println(e.message)
        }

        println("round-robbin load-balancing finished.")

        // finally send terminal packet to all consumer's MutableSharedFlows
        for (flow in mapOfFlows.values) {
            flow.emit(Packet(-1, "final", "final", true))
        }

        // might do something here _after_ the process has finished and its output is load-balanced to consumers
        // but consuming of process output has not finished yet.

        println("end of runBlocking ...")
    }
}

/** coroutine consuming from given Flow (which is a MutableSharedFlow!) */
suspend fun consume(name: String, flow: Flow<Packet>) {
    try {
        flow.buffer().collect { packet ->
            if (packet.isFinal)  { println("$name: final packet received") ; throw TerminatedException("'$name' terminated") }
            println("%5d in c%s: %s".format(packet.nr, name, packet.line))
            delay(Random.nextLong(50L, 550L))
        }
    } catch(e: TerminatedException) {
        println("consumer: ${e.message}")
    }
}

/** coroutine emitting to given producer's MutableSharedFlow */
suspend fun producer(name: String, cmd: String, producerFlow: MutableSharedFlow<Packet>) {
    val process = ProcessBuilder("\\s".toRegex().split(cmd))
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start() // non-blocking asynchronous start process in the background

    val inputBuffer = process.inputStream.source().buffer()
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
        val line = inputBuffer.readUtf8Line() ?: break
        producerFlow.emit(Packet(++i, cmd, line))
    }

    producerFlow.emit(Packet(-1, "final", "final", true))
    println("producer function ended")
}

// =====================================================================================================================
// =====================================================================================================================
// =====================================================================================================================

private fun showcaseSingleConsumer() {
    runBlocking {

        val flow: Flow<Packet> = singleProducer(name = "producer", cmd = "/Users/hoffi/gitRepos/scratch/scratch/some.sh")
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            singleConsumer(name = "consumer", flow)
        }

        // do something here, while the process is executed
        // and the consumer is consuming the process's output

        println("end of runBlocking ...")

    }
}

/** no suspend needed as a flow { ... } implicitly "runs in a coroutine" */
fun singleProducer(name: String, cmd: String) = flow {
    val process = ProcessBuilder("\\s".toRegex().split(cmd))
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start() // non-blocking asynchronous start process in the background

    val inputBuffer = process.inputStream.source().buffer()
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
        val line = inputBuffer.readUtf8Line() ?: break
        emit(Packet(++i, cmd, line))
    }

    println("producer function ended")
}

suspend fun singleConsumer(name: String, flow: Flow<Packet>) {
    flow.buffer().collect { packet ->
        println("%5d in c%s: %s".format(packet.nr, name, packet.line))
        delay(Random.nextLong(30L, 150L))
    }
}
```

`some.sh` shellscript used as "data source":

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 # some.sh
echo "first line"
echo -e "second line\nand third line"
echo -n "fourth line without newline"
sleep 2
echo
echo -e "fifth line after sleep\nand sixth line"
echo -e "some stderr\nand stderr has two lines" >&2
for i in {1..25}; do
  echo "and loop line $i"
done
echo -n "last line"
```